# Iteratively parse JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have 1000+ JSON files that look like

```js
{
    "name": "Some name",
    "part_num": "123456",

    "other_config": {
        // Large amount of objects
    },
    "some more": {
        // Large amount of objects
    }
    // etc
}
```

When my program starts up, it has to scan the directory with all these JSON files, load each one, and extract the `"name"` and `"part_num"` values and populates a list view with these values.  The user then selects one and that config is then re-parsed and the proper actions taken then.

The problem is reading that many files takes a while.  I've mitigated it somewhat by using `multiprocessing` to throw the work on all available cores in the background, then populating the list view once done, but I'm still bounded by IO.  Since I know this code will be running on computers with slower processors and hard drives than mine, this speed is not acceptable.

The average case scenario is that the values I need are at the beginning of the file, but I can't assume that in the worst case.  **Is there a way to iteratively parse a JSON file so that I can load what I need from these files faster?**

I could resort to regex, [but I'd really prefer not to](http://xkcd.com/1171/).

Comment: Or you could consolidate them into a SINGLE jsons tructure, e.g. an array of data, `[{stuff from file1},{stuff from file2},....]` so you're only loading a SINGLE file and parsing a SINGLE js structure.... or just use a database

Comment: Not use JSON files? Why not use a `sqlite` database for this data, for example? Scan the files just *once* if you have to.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a solution other than parsing all of those files every time your program starts up. Perhaps caching the results in a database, then only opening the files that have been added or changed since you last started?

Comment: Came here to say that. Build a single database or file (as if a file couldn't be a database in its own right) and then use this one. Of course only put the information relevant to the search in such a file (`name` and `part_num`)

Comment: @MarcB Requirements say no.  Each file represents a different product, and we want to keep these products separate from each other.  Non-programmers might have to edit these files, and it'd be a disaster if they accidentally edited the wrong part of a file.

Comment: I also can't opt for the database option.  I've suggested using a database several times, but I can't get the permission to.  This isn't a normal application, I work in test engineering so our software is rather constrained.

Comment: provide an edit-the-product interface then. if these files are that critical, you shouldn't let "commoners" edit them directly. ESPECIALLY since json syntax is so touchy. Your commoners **WILL** introduce syntax errors.

Comment: @MarcB Trust me, I know that there are things wrong with how it's implemented, but this is how I'm being told to implement it.  It's better than the code written entirely in Tcl where the "config" files were just pure Tcl and sourced to bring variables into scope.  If I had my way, it'd be MongoDB and only a handful of people would have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

[YAJL](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) is an event-driven parser with [Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yajl). This way you can stop parsing once you have retrieved the info you need.

Comment: This looks like it might be a good solution.  I'll update you later if it fits my needs and if I can get the all clear to use it on this project.

Comment: I like the look of the project, but it doesn't look like that it'll work in my case.  Do you know of any other libraries that can do the same thing?

Comment: To answer that it would be good to know why YAJL did not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This reminded me of XML back in the day, when we had three styles of parsers: DOM-based, event based (e.g., SAX), and lesser known pull-based (e.g., StAX). The latter two were more efficient, because they didn't require loading the entire file into memory when you only need bits of it.

Fortunately, similar things exist for JSON. For Python, take a look at [yajl-py](https://github.com/pykler/yajl-py), which is a Python wrapper for the C-library [Yajl](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/).

It takes a bit more code to parse via an event-based parser, but it can be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is [ijson](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson) which performs performs iterative json parsing in a pythonc way.

I guess that solution to your problem would be:

```
import ijson

f = open('...')
objects = ijson.items(f, 'other_config.item')
for part in objects:
    do_something_with(part)
```

**Dislaimer** I did not use that library.