# Error in parsing .json file using Python

Tags: python, json

I am getting the following error. What does it mean?

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

in code line : `writer.writerow({k:v.decode('utf8') for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()})`

My code looks like :

```
import json
import csv

def make_csv(data):
    fname = "try.csv"
    with open(fname,'wb') as outf:
        dic_list = data['bookmarks']
        dictionary =  dic_list[0]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outf,fieldnames = sorted(dictionary.keys()), restval = "None", extrasaction = 'ignore')
        writer.writeheader()

        for dictionary in dic_list:
            writer.writerow({k:v.decode('utf8') for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()})
    return


def main():
    fil = "readability.json"
    f = open(fil,'rb')
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    print type(data)
    make_csv(data)
```

The json file looks like :

```
{ "bookmarks" : [{..},{..} ..... {..}],
  "recommendations" : [{..},{..}...{..}]
}
```

where `[..]` = list and `{..}` = dictionary

EDIT :

The above problem was solved, But when I ran the above code, The CSV file generated has some discrepancies. Some rows were pasted randomly i.e. under different headers in .csv file. Any suggestions?

Comment: At some point, the value of v is a boolean (either True or False), so you're trying to do `True.decode()` or `False.decode()`, which doesn't work.  I expect this is a duplicate of some existing question.

Comment: I don't understand how is v boolean, at any point. It is string. The value against the key.

Comment: There's only one place that you're calling decode, and that's in `v.decode('utf8')`.  The error says `'bool' object has no attribute 'decode'`.  So the value of `v` is probably that bool object, which means that it's either `True` or `False` (since there aren't any other bool objects).

Comment: okay. I looked at the json file. There are some null values which are translated to `False` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Somewhere* in your `readability.json` file you have an entry that's a boolean value, like `true` or `false` (in JSON), translated to the Python `True` and `False` objects.

You should not be using `decode()` in the first place, however, as `json.loads()` *already* produces Unicode values for strings.

Since this is Python 2, you want to **encode** your data, to UTF-8, instead. Convert your objects to `unicode` first:

```
writer.writerow({
    k: unicode(v).encode('utf8')
    for k ,v in dictionary.iteritems()
})
```

Converting existing Unicode strings to `unicode` is a no-op, but for integers, floating point values, `None` and boolean values you'll get a nice Unicode representation that can be encoded to UTF-8:

```
>>> unicode(True).encode('utf8')
'True'
```

Comment: Could you suggest me a way to read BIG .json file? I could not find any suitable code to help me. My file is 5MB. However, for the sake of running code, I manually deleted a lot of data so that I can parse and see if it works. 
What can I do?

Comment: @SilentSpy: the standard library `json` module can only parse the whole file in one go. See [Iteratively parse JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20885797) for iterative parsing options.

Comment: @SilentSpy: alternatively, write *separate* JSON objects to the file with newlines as separators. See [Loading and parsing a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12451431) for how to read such a file.

Comment: There's an Error in the .csv file parsed. Some rows are randomly pasted beneath columns. How do I sort this?

Comment: @SilentSpy: you mean there are embedded newlines? Then your original value had those newlines, and the column will be *quoted* to signal to a compliant CSV parser to preserve those newlines.

Comment: @SilentSpy: note that if you have new problems it is better to ask a new question (after due research). Help in comments never can get very far.